# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:Index 12 out of bounds for length 12

Tags: java, maps, 2d, game-development

I'm currently trying to make a 2D game using VSCode, I am on a MacBook, and keep getting this error whenever trying to load the map. My map for some reason will only appear as all white, without the character, and I get this error in the terminal:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
at tile.TileManager.draw(TileManager.java:102)
at main.GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:94)

Here is my TileManager class

```
package tile;

import main.GamePanel;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.*;

public class TileManager {

    GamePanel gp;
    Tile[] tile;
    int mapTileNum[][];

    public TileManager(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;

        tile = new Tile[10];

        mapTileNum = new int[gp.maxWorldCol][gp.maxScreenRow];

        getTileImage();
        loadMap("res/maps/world01.txt");
    }

    public void getTileImage() {

        System.out.println("image loading started");

        try {

            this.tile[0] = new Tile();
            this.tile[0].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/grass01.png"));

            this.tile[1] = new Tile();
            this.tile[1].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/wall.png"));

            this.tile[2] = new Tile();
            this.tile[2].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/water01.png"));

            this.tile[3] = new Tile();
            this.tile[3].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/earth.png"));

            this.tile[4] = new Tile();
            this.tile[4].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/tree.png"));

            this.tile[5] = new Tile();
            this.tile[5].image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/tiles/sand.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Image loading finished");
    }

    public void loadMap(String filePath) {
        try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            int col = 0;
            int row = 0;

            while (col < gp.maxWorldCol && row < gp.maxWorldRow) {
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (col < gp.maxWorldCol) {
                    String numbers[] = line.split(" "); // splits up strings at space
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers[col]);
                    mapTileNum[col][row] = num;
                    col++;
                }

                if (col == gp.maxWorldCol) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

        int worldCol = 0;
        int worldRow = 0;

        while (worldCol < gp.maxWorldCol && worldRow < gp.maxWorldRow) {

            int tileNum = mapTileNum[worldCol][worldRow];

            int worldX = worldCol * gp.tileSize;
            int worldY = worldRow * gp.tileSize;
            int screenX = worldX - gp.player.worldX + gp.player.screenX;
            int screenY = worldY - gp.player.worldY + gp.player.screenY;

            if (worldX + gp.tileSize > gp.player.worldX - gp.player.screenX &&
                    worldX - gp.tileSize < gp.player.worldX + gp.player.screenX &&
                    worldY + gp.tileSize > gp.player.worldY - gp.player.screenY &&
                    worldY - gp.tileSize < gp.player.worldY + gp.player.screenY) {

                        g2.drawImage(tile[tileNum].image, screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
            }

            g2.drawImage(tile[tileNum].image, screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
            worldCol++;

            if (worldCol == gp.maxWorldCol) {
                worldCol = 0;
                worldRow++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never silently ignore exceptions `catch (Exception e) {

        }
`

Answer (score 0):

In the public tile manager call the getTileImage method to initialize the tiles

```
    public TileManager(GamePanel gp) {
    this.gp = gp;
    tile = new Tile[10];
    getTileImage();  // Call the getTileImage method to initialize the tiles
}
```